# How to add my JAR lib to tomcat7 installation in ubuntu

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, tomcat7

I am trying to set up an ubuntu server with tomcat7, I installed tomcat7 using the command `sudo apt-get install tomcat7` in Ubuntu.

I have some shared libraries across my applications like JSTL and other stuff so I would like to make them in the webserver include folder.

I have put them everywhere in the server directories after searching the internet but they never get loaded, where is the correct location to put them?

I've done this in windows and it worked great, but in Ubuntu, it does not seem to work, or should I install tomcat some other way?

Comment: Have you identified in which folder is Tomcat installed?

Comment: Don't. Really, don't. The libraries should be indide the WEB-INF/lib folder of each webapp. That's what will allows you to udate it in one webapp without updating it in all the other ones.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree with you, but in this case looks like OP wants/needs that all the web applications share JSTL libraries, which won't be a bad practice (not like adding spring mvc or jsf libraries for all projects, which could be bad if you will never use features of those frameworks in your app). It depends on what kind of libraries you should add to the application server loader.

Comment: Even the JSTL might very well evolve over time, and a new webapp could want to use the new version some time later.

Comment: I've had some issues with trying to make all versions consistent across my applications, so thats why I needed this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing tomcat7 package in Ubuntu, you create your own instance of tomcat using **tomcat-instance-create <dir>**. Among other files, that command creates <dir>/conf/catalina.properties, which defines

`common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/common/classes,${catalina.home}/common/*.jar`

If your jar is in any of the places referred to by common.loader, it will be shared among all applications in the instance. CATALINA_BASE is the <dir> you specified in tomcat-instance-create. So, to keep your common libraries between tomcat7 package updates, place them into **<dir>/lib**

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend against doing that.

You might run into problems with classloaders, and the shared libraries not being able to see your code.

The common approach to this, is to deploy shared code as part of an EAR but plain Tomcat implements too little of Java EE to support this.  For this level, just deploy what  you need and leave it at that.   This also makes it easier to switch containers if you need it - Jetty is a nice alternative to development.

Comment: But its not very good if I deploy same libraries over and over again in each web app, it makes bigger in size and if we want to change some library we would have to go through all the apps to change it then redeploy all of them again, seems a waste of time

Comment: Redeployment should not be much of an issue unless you have a very slow connection to the server.  The "what if we update our libraries" part is a much more interesting point which leads to how you manage your software, especially the part on how to maintain the software as delivered to customers.

Answer (score 0):

using the command you proveded my lib is located at

/usr/share/tomcat7/lib

if you are on ubunto you can try something like

locate tomcat7/lib

Answer (score -4):

yOU HAVE TO CREATE AN INSTANCE FOR YOUR APPLICATION AND AFTER THIS ONE FOLDER WILL BE CREATED WITH ALL CONFIGURATION, NORMALLY UNDER /etc/tomcat7/TEST-INSTANCE THIS IS IN THE CASE WHEN YOU NAME YOUR INSTANCE AS TEST-INSTANCE. iNSIDE THIS FOLDER YOU CAN FIND ANOTHER FOLDER NAMED webapp WHERE YOU CAN DEPLOY YOUR APPLICATION. ALSO THERE IS ANOTHER FOLDER NAMED bin WHERE YOU CAN INITIALIZE TOMCAT7 SERVER RUNNING ./startup.sh COMMAND. IN THE FOLLOWING LINK YOU CAN SEE A DEEPER DESCRIPTION
https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/tomcat.html