# apache tomcat throws: no ocijdbc11 in java.library.path in linux

Tags: linux, oracle, database-connection, tomcat8

In Linux system, I am trying to connect Oracle db with my application(some servlets), which is hosted in Apache tomcat 8.0.
    On running the tomcat, the catalina.out is throwing below error:
     **java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ocijdbc11 in java.library.path**

I saw lot of threads speaking about the missing ocijdbc11.dll file and suggests us to add it in windows/eclipse environment.
  But in Linux how can I fix this issue?? I don't want to use oracle thin driver, because I don't have the IP & other stuffs of oracle db which is running remotely.
 Your suggestion/solutions will help me a lot thanks in advance...

Comment: You can fix it by not using a DLL.  Oracle has a pure Java, type IV JDBC driver that you can use without relying on native code.  I can't think of a good reason why you use anything else.  You should get over your reluctance.  How can you not have information about the remote database?

Comment: Please show your code that's causing the error. Please show your path. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably all you need is to install oracle client somwhere and add this path to common loader. Second option is just using ojdbc.jar instead of oci. Try reading this how to configure path: [How to add my JAR lib to tomcat7 installation in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883449/how-to-add-my-jar-lib-to-tomcat7-installation-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!!! I solved it there was a problem with installed oracle client in my machine..switching to the correct one solved it.
sol: download oracle instant client and unzip it, give the correct path in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on the dynamic web Application and add path, where you can add jar file..before adding please confirm the type of jdbc driver. Mostly type 4 is recommended.